# Simulating Animation jQTouch

Tags: javascript, jqtouch

I would like to simulate an animation jQTouch in this function:

```
$(function(){
$('#form').submit( function(e){
        $.get('/result.php', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=data;   
    });
    CODE?!?
});
```

The function retrieves the data and writes it to the div "result", I would that after writing data, make an animation '.slideup' from #home to #result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQT.goTo(Page, Animation)` to transit to another "page" with a specified animation, e.g.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    $.get('/result.php', function(data) {
        $("result").html(data);
        jQT.goTo('#result', 'slideup');
    });
});
```

Here's the documentation: https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/functions.